# Manifest Merger error when adding dependencies for CardView.

Tags: android, dependencies, cardview

Whenever I try to add dependencies for CardView, Android Studio is showing the following error:

**[**> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from
> >     [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31     is
> >     also present at [com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1]
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).    Suggestion: add
> >     'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.**][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoSiO.png)**

Comment: Do not mix support library versions

Comment: PLEASE EXPLAIN BRIEFLY

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might have set compile-sdk and target-sdk to 25. Change dependency to compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'.